# Xubuntu black screen, no login window, fresh install

Tags: 10.10

I recently installed kubuntu on a very old iMac (self contained unit, no tower, G2?) 800mhz.

The xubuntu installation went well from the mini cd.  I installed the kubuntu desktop package (at the installer window).  I restarted and I see a black screen with white text, asking if I want to boot off Linux or the cd.  It changes to white, then to black screen white text.  It says something about a yaboot loader and it pauses for a few seconds then it changes to another screen that has a white screen with black text.  It says something about prom_init.  It changes to a blue screen that says "Kubuntu" and has dots at the bottom.  It appears to be loading until...

The screen turns black (with a blacklight) and flickers purple and red.  The backlight turns off, and it stays there forever. I can't hear any disk activity. I tried pressing alt+F2 to F12.  Nothing pops up.  I was doing a fresh install of xubuntu.  If I hold down the shift key during startup nothing changes.  There is no grub menu, I booted from the cd and tried to find the recovery menu, none.  No login sounds.  I tried pressing "e" nothing changes with the startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reinstall Xubuntu because the installation was half-finished and corrupted.